# Alternative of hash map which is faster

Tags: hashmap, hashcode

What is the alternative of hash map which will provide faster functionality.

I need to put values in key , value pair.As per Hash map functionality whenever we will add new key , value pair it will search the key into existing pairs and will add key if not exists .I want to omit this search as in required data key will never be repeated.

Can I override put method of hashmap .

Comment: one solution improving the efficiency would be using dictionary instead of hashtable/hashmap. there is no boxing or unboxing, which saves some time.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that HashMap is really too slow? The process of removing the existing mapping cannot be much overhead, as you already need to find the bucket to put the new mapping in. The only thing that could conceivably be slow (for some definition of slow...) would be linear search due to hash bucket collisions. You can minimize that by sizing the map accordingly (low fill factor).

Comment: program is fetching values from database into resultset and putting values into hashmap through iterating the resultset .  This iteration and putting values into hasmap is taking lot of time as there is huge data in table.Later I need to get values from the hashmap by providing key values.I need to reduce the time of putting values into hashmap.

Comment: From your last comment it sounds like optimizing your SQL query to narrow down the result set might be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Check your hash function first, it may turn out that hash map is slow because there are a lot of collisions between hash values for different keys; it leads to inefficient hash table operations.

Also, reserve enough capacity ahead of the insertion operation in order to prevent costly resize operations and check your load factor to be not too high (1-10 is generally good).

Comment: By Hash fuction you are indicating hash code() function. This function is not being override in our program

Comment: I'm not sure which language/framework we are talking about, so, my answer was purely theoretical and should be mapped for a specific language/framework's implementation of hash table algorithm.